# Monitor progress/Print to console from purrr::invoke_map()

Tags: r, dplyr, r-caret, tidyverse, purrr

I'm attempting to train several `caret` models from within a list-column format in R (see: [this blog post](http://rsangole.netlify.com/post/pur-r-ify-your-carets/?utm_content=buffer2e597&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)) using `purrr::invoke_map()`.

When calling `invoke_map()`, I'd like to be able to monitor the progress in some way. Specifically, I'd like to print the row number, or the `id` column as `invoke_map()` iterates through the model/data combinations. Is there a way to do this, possibly by modifying the training function (`linearRegModel()` below)?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
data("BostonHousing") # from mlbench


starter_df <- 
  list(BostonHousing) %>% 
  rep(3) %>% 
  enframe(name = 'id', value = 'rawdata')  %>% 
  transmute(
    id
    , train.X = map(rawdata,  ~ .x %>% select(-medv))
    , train.Y = map(rawdata, ~ .x$medv)
  )



# re-write any caret training method as a function. 
# using linear regression here for simplicity
linearRegModel <- function(X, Y) {
 ctrl <- trainControl(
    method = "repeatedcv", 
    number = 2
  )
  train(
    x = X,
    y = Y,
    method = 'lm',
    trControl = ctrl,
    preProc = c('center', 'scale')
  )
}


# convert models to tibble
model_list <- 
  list(linearRegModel = linearRegModel,
       linearRegModel2 = linearRegModel) %>%
  enframe(name = 'modelName',value = 'model')

# combine model tibble with the data tibble
train_df <- 
  starter_df[rep(1:nrow(starter_df),nrow(model_list)),] %>% 
  bind_cols(
    model_list[rep(1:nrow(model_list),nrow(starter_df)),] %>% arrange(modelName)
  ) %>%
  mutate(id=1:nrow(.))

train_df



# A tibble: 6 x 5
     id                 train.X     train.Y       modelName  model
  <int>                  <list>      <list>           <chr> <list>
1     1 <data.frame [506 x 13]> <dbl [506]>  linearRegModel  <fun>
2     2 <data.frame [506 x 13]> <dbl [506]>  linearRegModel  <fun>
3     3 <data.frame [506 x 13]> <dbl [506]>  linearRegModel  <fun>
4     4 <data.frame [506 x 13]> <dbl [506]> linearRegModel2  <fun>
5     5 <data.frame [506 x 13]> <dbl [506]> linearRegModel2  <fun>
6     6 <data.frame [506 x 13]> <dbl [506]> linearRegModel2  <fun>


# train models by calling invoke_map()
# (takes a few seconds)
data_with_model_fits <-
  train_df %>%
  mutate(params = map2(train.X, train.Y,  ~ list(X = .x, Y = .y)),
         modelFits = invoke_map(model,params)
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the `progress` package interesting. Below I've integrated it into your problem. Note two things:

- You initialize the progress bar before you begin to fit the models with `progress::progress_bar(tick = number_of_ticks)`.
- Inside the `linRegModel()` function you "tick" the progress bar forward after the model has been fit with `pb$tick()`.

`pb` is an `R6` object using object oriented techniques, so you do not have to pass it into your `linRegModel()` function as an argument.

Hope it helps.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbench)
library(caret)

data("BostonHousing") # from mlbench

library(progress)

starter_df <- 
    list(BostonHousing) %>% 
    rep(3) %>% 
    enframe(name = 'id', value = 'rawdata')  %>% 
    transmute(
        id
        , train.X = map(rawdata,  ~ .x %>% select(-medv))
        , train.Y = map(rawdata, ~ .x$medv)
    )



# re-write any caret training method as a function. 
# using linear regression here for simplicity
linearRegModel <- function(X, Y) {
    ctrl <- trainControl(
        method = "repeatedcv", 
        number = 2
    )
    train(
        x = X,
        y = Y,
        method = 'lm',
        trControl = ctrl,
        preProc = c('center', 'scale')
    )

    # Tick the progress bar forward 1 tick after each completed model fit
    pb$tick()
}


# convert models to tibble
model_list <- 
    list(linearRegModel = linearRegModel,
         linearRegModel2 = linearRegModel) %>%
    enframe(name = 'modelName',value = 'model')

# combine model tibble with the data tibble
train_df <- 
    starter_df[rep(1:nrow(starter_df),nrow(model_list)),] %>% 
    bind_cols(
        model_list[rep(1:nrow(model_list),nrow(starter_df)),] %>% arrange(modelName)
    ) %>%
    mutate(id=1:nrow(.))

train_df


# initialize progress bar
ticks <- nrow(train_df)
pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(total = ticks)

# train models by calling invoke_map()
# (takes a few seconds)
data_with_model_fits <-
train_df %>%
mutate(params = map2(train.X, train.Y,  ~ list(X = .x, Y = .y)),
       modelFits = invoke_map(model,params)
)
```

For added flexibility, you can use a `token` through the `format` argument when creating the progress bar. A few are built in, like `:current` to show you the current iteration. This might more directly answer your question. I would call `pb$tick()` before the model runs in this case. The documentation also advises running `pb$tick(0)` before a long running computation to immediately show the progress bar.

```
# initialize progress bar
pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(format = "running model :current", show_after = .01)
pb$tick(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves the issue and using token I can print the individual models as they are run.